# How do I recreate command run by Maven's antrun plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 on Solaris 10.  I am using the antrun exec plugin.  How do I figure out the command line statement that is actually being run?  When running my command (designed to checkout code from the StarTeam version control system), I'm getting a permission denied error, although I have verified my user has proper perms.  I would like to run the same command Maven is running from a shell so that I can compare the two commands.

Below is the relevant section from my pom.xml file …

```
                    <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <phase>verify</phase>
                                            <configuration>

                                                    <tasks> 

                                                            <!-- Backup CIRQUE_COMPLETE and freeze the backup label -->
                                                            <exec failonerror="true" executable="stcmd" dir="/opt/StarTeamCP_2009/bin/">
                                                                    <arg value="label" />
                                                                    <arg value="-p" />
                                                                    <arg value="user:@mydomain.com:49201/myco/myco/Technology/nna/mycoUSA/cirquedusoleil" />
                                                                    <arg value="-vl" />
                                                                    <arg value="CIRQUE_${env}_COMPLETE" />
                                                                    <arg value="-nl" />
                                                                    <arg value="CIRQUE_${env}_COMPLETE_`date +&quot;%Y%m%d-%T&quot;`" />
                                                                    <arg value="-f" />
                                                                    <arg value="-r" />
                                                            </exec>

                                                            <!-- Slide CIRQUE_COMPLETE label up to build label -->
                                                            <exec failonerror="true" executable="stcmd" dir="/opt/StarTeamCP_2009/bin/">
                                                                    <arg value="apply-label" />
                                                                    <arg value="-p" />
                                                                    <arg value="user:@mydomain.com:49201/myco/myco/Technology/nna/mycoUSA/cirquedusoleil" />
                                                                    <arg value="-vl" />
                                                                    <arg value="${env.BUILD_ID}" />
                                                                    <arg value="-lbl" />
                                                                    <arg value="CIRQUE_${env}_COMPLETE" />
                                                                    <arg value="-is" />
                                                                    <arg value="*" />
                                                            </exec>

                                                    </tasks>
                                            </configuration>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run maven with the `-X` option.  This will give you more (debug) information and it will also run ant with the `-debug` option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'chmod' tag before 'exec' to guarantee the right to execute the command, as follows:

```
<chmod file="/opt/StarTeamCP_2009/bin/stcmd" perm="a+x"/>

<exec failonerror="true" executable="stcmd" dir="/opt/StarTeamCP_2009/bin/">
  ...
</exec>
```